# How to get data from elements inside one element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get some data out of HTML elements. Data is duplicated. Imagine a Survey page showing you results for many questions:

Here is my example of the main element container of the information for each question: 
[image]

Each "div" element is a container. Inside I can find elements "div, tr, td", etc. I would like to create an script to navigate thru each container and get same data: Like Question number, Question text, Response options text, values, etc.

[image]

Here is what I tried so far:

```
var title = $('.sm-question-view').contents().find('.sm-question-number');
```

My intention was to get the sm-question-number inside of one of the containers "sm-question-view" but instead I get a list of all "sm-question-number" available in the page. Which to me makes it more difficult to manage since I was planning to store data in csv format per question.

I also tried only with:

```
var title = $('.sm-question-view');
```

title retrieves the object, and I can navigate thru it to find all items, but also navigation is complicated since there are a lot of elements that I need to go thru to get the final text that I want.

My logic in my mind can be represented with this pseudocode:

For each container:

csv_string = Find(question-number).text;

csv_string += Find(question-title).text;

csv_string += Find(question-view-sub-header).text;

csv_string += Find(label-txt-shadow-it).text;

Of course this pseudocode is just brief representation of what I would like to achive. 
Any thoughts?  I will keep reading about usage of "find()" but any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Great try and thanks for posting your code for us to see. have you tried with just: `var title = $('.sm-question-view').find('.sm-question-number');` ? have you looked at the JS doc for the `find()` method? it generally returns an array (even if there's only one thing to be found). But there are other similar find-like methods in javascript - eg have you looked at functions like `first()` ?

Comment: I tried but did not work as expected

Comment: it's always a good idea to include everything you have tried in your question - along with the results you got, and why the results didn't help you... otherwise other people trying to help you will go up the same blind alleys you did - and waste both our times :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pseudo-code is practically correct:

```
const wrapper = $('.sm-question-view');

let csv_string = '';
wrapper.each(function() {
  csv_string =  $(this).find(number).text() + ',';
  csv_string += $(this).find(title).text() + ',';
  csv_string += $(this).find(view - sub - header).text() + ',';
  csv_string += $(this).find(label - txt - shadow - it).text() + ',';
  csv_string += '\n';
});
```

Now replace the values inside `.find()` with your selectors.

If you aren't familiar with `.find()`, think of it like that: It does exactly what `$(…)` does, just that it only searches inside the other element.

Also note that you will need the `.each()` here since you actually want more methods on the same element in a row.

Comment: thanks and just have one clarification for the solution above, In order to properly make the .find() to search for your selector(a class in this case) only within the element retrieved it was needed to use the sintax $(this).find()

Comment: oh my bad ^^ Changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is to add a class to every bit of information that you need to retrieve (i.e. sm-question-number, sm-question-title,...)

Then, you can loop through a list of your question by doing the below code:

```
$('.sm-question-view').each(function(index, el) { // loop through each question
    const title = $(this).children('.sm-question-title').text();
    // this points to the current question that is looping
    // find() function search through the element's descendant to find the class
});
```